# Mirror Windows Screen to RPi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, networking

i want to mirror my Windows 10 Desktop to my Raspberry Pi.
If possible real time but a little delay is alright. 
I want to be able to watch Netflix on it but i dont want to install Kodi or any other OS on it. I want to run everything on raspbian 2018.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install RealVNC server on Windows and RealVNC viewer on your Raspberry and that should allow you to mirrow a Windows 10 desktop on your RPi.

RealVNC is usually run the other way round with the server on the Raspberry and the viewer on Windows.

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/

Comment: netflix wont be watchable :p

Comment: normally yes but with a mirrored pc screen which is running netflix it will probably.